PureScript: how to wait for child to exit?
I'm writing a backend, and I need to execute certain command with text passed via stdin, then read the result from stdout. Such utilities provided by Node.ChildProcess module, except I don't see any way to wait till child exits. Which is odd, because there's no point in reading from stdout if the app didn't write anything there yet.
In terms of a minimal example I'm using cat. cat reads text from stdin and writes to stdout.
module Main where

import Prelude

import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (log)
import Node.ChildProcess as Proc
import Node.Encoding (Encoding(UTF8))
import Node.Stream as Stream

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  child :: Proc.ChildProcess <- Proc.spawn "cat" []
  let
    stdin' :: Stream.Writable ()
    stdin' = Proc.stdin child
  _ <- Stream.writeString stdin' UTF8 "hello"
  _ <- Stream.end stdin'

  -- wait for child ?? How?

  let
    stdout' :: Stream.Readable ()
    stdout' = Proc.stdout child
  output :: Maybe String <- Stream.readString stdout' UTF8
  case output of
    Just s -> log s
    _      -> log "nothing"

I want this to print hello, because that's what cat writes to its stdout. Instead unsurprisingly I get "nothing", because by the time Stream.readString is executed cat didn't write anything to stdout yet.
How do I wait for cat to exit?

When the process exits, Node will fire an "exit" event, which is mapped to PureScript as exitH, and you can attach a listener to it with the on_ function from Node.EventEmitter.
Since your program is all synchronous (runs in Effect), you should put everything that should happen after the child's exit inside the "exit" event handler:
main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  child :: Proc.ChildProcess <- Proc.spawn "cat" []
  let
    stdin' :: Stream.Writable ()
    stdin' = Proc.stdin child
  _ <- Stream.writeString stdin' UTF8 "hello"
  _ <- Stream.end stdin'

  child # on_ Proc.exitH \_ -> do
    let
      stdout' :: Stream.Readable ()
      stdout' = Proc.stdout child
    output :: Maybe String <- Stream.readString stdout' UTF8
    case output of
      Just s -> log s
      _      -> log "nothing"


Thank you! You said "since your program is all synchronous" — do you mean there's a different strategy for the Aff case? My actual program is asynchronous, however the way I see it is that since everything mentioned in the code above supposed to run consequently, I should put it to a separate Effect function, and then run this function from the Aff monad. Unless I misunderstand something, Aff operates on plain Effect, and I presume the way it works is that when the Effect above will be waiting in a system call the program will switch to executing something else asynchronous.

Answering my comment: actually, reading "Demystifying Aff Monad I see that nothing in Aff is asynchronous unless you explicitly called forkAff function. IOW, every call inside Aff monad is synchronous unless you explicitly told otherwise. Which I guess both makes Aff monad useless and answers my commentary question: no, there's no difference whether this code runs inside Effect or Aff. As a matter of fact, Effect is always better because you don't need to call liftEffect.

I think you misunderstood. Parallelism and asynchrony are different things.

The difference is that asynchronous may be single-threaded, I know. That doesn't diminish my comments though, they were written with that in mind.

I just realized, neither on nor on_ provides a way to retrieve a value. How do I do that then? So for example, getting stdout to send it elsewhere.

Nvm, I found spawnSync' function. I think I've seen it before too, but I haven't realized it's possible to use it this way because it doesn't mention stdin. And I was searching for stdin keyword in the sources and docs.

Fyodor I have a suspicion, so, you know, just checking: by any chance, do you know who could be stalking me on my PureScript posts?

As a complementary answer, it isn't uncommon to have to retrieve the output in the same code that spawned external process and not being able to postpone that to some later time. In this case the on_ hook mentioned in the accepted answer won't work.
The way to do that is by using spawnSync' this way:
module Main where

import Prelude

import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (log)
import Node.ChildProcess as Proc
import Node.ChildProcess.Types as Proc
import Node.Encoding (Encoding(UTF8))
import Node.Buffer as Buf

isOkayExitcode :: Proc.Exit -> Boolean
isOkayExitcode (Proc.Normally x) = x == 0
isOkayExitcode _ = false

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  input :: Buf.Buffer <- Buf.fromString "hello" UTF8
  let
    options :: Proc.SpawnSyncOptions -> Proc.SpawnSyncOptions
    options o = o {input = Just input}
  result <- Proc.spawnSync' "cat" [] options
  case isOkayExitcode result.exitStatus of
    true -> do
      stdout :: String <- Buf.toString UTF8 result.stdout
      log stdout
    false -> log "Program exited with error"


Hmm, someone is stalking me. It's not the first purescript-related post that is well written but gets silently downvoted by an unknown person. Funnily enough, I have an actually bad PS post made based on misunderstanding, and it wasn't downvoted. Very interesting.
